# Flutter: What is the correct way to detect touch enter, move and exit on CustomPainter objects

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am beginner in Flutter and I am trying to figure how I can detect touch enter, move and exit when a user runs their finger across a custom shape and/or across multiple stacked custom shapes. Something like below

[image]

Ideally I would like to get touch events when users enter/exit pixel boundaries of each custom shape, but I wanted to get it working at-least with a MBR of the shapes. Below is the code that I have. What am I doing wrong? All it seems to do is print move when touch begins within the shapes. I have tried GestureDetector too with similar results.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepOrange,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Listener(
                  onPointerSignal: (PointerEvent details) {
                    print("Signal yellow");
                  },
                  onPointerMove: (PointerEvent details) {
                    print("Move yellow");
                  },
                  onPointerHover: (PointerEvent details) {
                    print("Hover yellow");
                  },
                  onPointerEnter: (PointerEvent details) {
                    print("Enter yellow");
                  },
                  onPointerExit: (PointerEvent details) {
                    print("Exit yellow");
                  },
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: ShapesPainter(),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 400,
                      width: 400,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Listener(
                  onPointerEnter: (PointerEvent details) {
                    print("Enter red");
                  },
                  onPointerExit: (PointerEvent details) {
                    print("Exit red");
                  },
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: ShapesPainter1(),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShapesPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    // set the color property of the paint
    paint.color = Colors.yellow;
    // center of the canvas is (x,y) => (width/2, height/2)
    var center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    // draw the circle on centre of canvas having radius 75.0
    canvas.drawCircle(center, size.width / 2, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    // TODO: implement hitTest
    return super.hitTest(position);
  }
}

class ShapesPainter1 extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    // set the color property of the paint
    paint.color = Colors.red;
    // center of the canvas is (x,y) => (width/2, height/2)
    var center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    // draw the circle on centre of canvas having radius 75.0
    canvas.drawCircle(center, size.width / 2, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    // TODO: implement hitTest
    return super.hitTest(position);
  }
}
```

Comment: wrap it with GesturesDetector that's it

Comment: You are looking for https://github.com/nateshmbhat/touchable . This package lets you add all types of gesture callbacks to each shape you draw on the canvas

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's because you are using one `Listener` per `CustomPainter`, you should use just one `Listener` for all your `Stack`.

And if you want to know if the current touch event is inside each Circle , you could use `GlobalKey`s to get the `RenderBox` for each Circle, then you have the renderBox, and the `PointerEvent`, you can easily check the HitTest, check the code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey _keyYellow = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey _keyRed = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text("title"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Listener(
              onPointerMove: (PointerEvent details) {
                final RenderBox box = _keyRed.currentContext.findRenderObject();
                final RenderBox boxYellow =
                    _keyYellow.currentContext.findRenderObject();
                final result = BoxHitTestResult();
                Offset localRed = box.globalToLocal(details.position);
                Offset localYellow = boxYellow.globalToLocal(details.position);
                if (box.hitTest(result, position: localRed)) {
                  print("HIT...RED ");
                } else if (boxYellow.hitTest(result, position: localYellow)) {
                  print("HIT...YELLOW ");
                }
              },
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  CustomPaint(
                    key: _keyYellow,
                    painter: ShapesPainter(),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 400,
                      width: 400,
                    ),
                  ),
                  CustomPaint(
                    key: _keyRed,
                    painter: ShapesPainter1(),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also I modified the `hitTest` method of your `CustomPainter`s to ignore the touchs outside the circle.

```
class ShapesPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    // set the color property of the paint
    paint.color = Colors.yellow;
    // center of the canvas is (x,y) => (width/2, height/2)
    final center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    // draw the circle on centre of canvas having radius 75.0
    canvas.drawCircle(center, size.width / 2, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    final Offset center = Offset(200, 200);
    Path path = Path();
    path.addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 400, height: 400),
        Radius.circular(center.dx)));
    path.close();
    return path.contains(position);
  }
}

class ShapesPainter1 extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    // set the color property of the paint
    paint.color = Colors.red;
    // center of the canvas is (x,y) => (width/2, height/2)
    var center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    // draw the circle on centre of canvas having radius 75.0
    canvas.drawCircle(center, size.width / 2, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    return true;
  }

  @override
  bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    final Offset center = Offset(100, 100);
    Path path = Path();
    path.addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 200, height: 200),
        Radius.circular(center.dx)));
    path.close();
    return path.contains(position);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, that helped me

Comment: If I have more paths like map. then ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya got any solution?

Answer (score 4):

I have developed a library called
[touchable](https://pub.dev/packages/touchable) for the purpose of adding gesture callbacks to each individual shape you draw on the canvas.

Here's what you can do to detect touch and drag on your circle.

Just Wrap your CustomPaint widget with CanvasTouchDetector. It takes a builder function as argument that expects your CustomPaint widget as shown below.

```dart
import 'package:touchable/touchable.dart';


CanvasTouchDetector(
    builder: (context) => 
        CustomPaint(
            painter: MyPainter(context)
        )
)
```

Inside your CustomPainter class's paint method , create and use the TouchyCanvas object (using the context obtained from the CanvasTouchDetector and canvas) to draw your shape and you can give gesture callbacks like onPanUpdate , onTapDown here to detect your drag events.

```
var myCanvas = TouchyCanvas(context,canvas);
myCanvas.drawRect( rect , Paint() , onPanUpdate: (detail){
    //This callback runs when you drag this rectangle. Details of the location can be got from the detail object.
    //Do stuff here. Probably change your state and animate
});
```

Comment: hello, i already implement touchable, but when using onPanUpdate to change position, is working only when drag slow, but when drag little bit fast and cursor outside the line is not working anymore, any solution?